# old windfinder forecast googlemap

Tags: maps, surfing

On [www.windfinder.com](http://www.windfinder.com/weather-maps/forecast/denmark) they changed the forecast map. now it looks like this:

[image: new interactive map]

before, it had much more details, and you could zoom in it to find out the perfect spot for the forecasted wind direction:

[image: old google map]

see http://blog.windfinder.com/post/20001171353/wind-forecasts-on-google-maps

are these googlemap-forecasts still available somewhere?

Comment: Have you got your pictures the wrong way round? The first one seems to have much more info.

Comment: nothing wrong here: the new map is the first one. It is not that bad, only in the old map you could zoom in further. that's why I would like to have access to the old map too still

Answer (score 2):

The data from the old wind forecasts probably came from NOAA, and it's available [here](http://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/waves/viewer.shtml?-multi_1-latest-hs-NE_atlantic-). The raw data is in the form of GRIB files.

You can do a search for "GRIB Viewer" and find some apps that will work. You can also search for "GRIB KML", and might be able to download grib files in a KML/KMZ format that can be shown on Google Earth or Google Maps.

Comment: Can you show how to take the data for Denmark and include them in googlemaps? is it possible to show them in the online googlemaps?

Comment: I asked this here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44349/add-foreign-map-data-in-google-maps-online

Comment: It's possible, but I don't know how exactly. There might be some free apps. There are several commercial, such as Grib Explorer (http://www.ocens.com/GRIB-Explorer-P212.aspx). NOAA has the data format on their web site in case you can write an app for it.

Comment: I'd rather don't want any app for it, but have it directly shown inside http://maps.google.de

Comment: This might help: http://forums.sailinganarchy.com/index.php?showtopic=44194